# Psql not null error but value isn't null

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I'm trying to load data from one table into another, from all_address into customer.

I successfully insert into the customer table like so

```
INSERT INTO Customer(username, password, customer_email, first_name, 
    last_name, middle_initial)
SELECT username, password, customer_email, first_name, 
    last_name, middle_initial
FROM all_user;
```

However whenever I try to get the street address, city, and zip by doing

```
INSERT INTO Customer(street_address, city, zip_code)
SELECT temp.street_address, temp.city, 
      temp.zip_code
FROM all_address as temp, Customer as final
WHERE temp.customer_email = final.customer_email;
```

I get an error :

psql:manip.sql:82: ERROR:  null value in column "username" violates not-null              constraint

As username is a primary key, I don't understand why I'm getting the error as I've made sure to create customers WITH usernames so there isn't a null value in username as the error says.

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are not providing a `username` value in the second query.  There is probably no default and no mechanism for setting the value, so it is defaulting to `NULL`.

You need to provide a value.  It is possible that you intend an `update` rather than an `insert`:

```
update Customer c 
    set street_address = aa.street_address,
        city = aa.city, 
        zip_code = aa.zip_code
from all_address aa
where aa.customer_email = c.customer_email;
```

Comment: syntax was a bit off for psql, needed to do 
`update Customer c
    set street_address = aa.street_address,
        city = aa.city, 
        zip_code = aa.zip_code
from all_address aa
where aa.customer_email = c.customer_email; ` but that worked thanks!

Comment: @AnnaGoldberg . . . Leaving the column names in the first line was an editing mistake on my part.  I'm glad you readily caught it.